# Expressing $x_{1} ^ n + x_{2}^ n$, where $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ are the roots of $ax^2 +bx+c=0$

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

The roots $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$ of

$$ax^{2}+bx+c=0 $$

satisfy

$$ x_{1}+x_{2}=\frac{-b}{a} $$  and  $$x_{1}x_{2}=\frac{c}{a}$$

I need *Mathematica* to give me $x_{1} ^ n + x_{2}^ n$ for any $n$; that is:

$${x_{1}}^{2}+{x_{2}}^{2}=(x_{1}+x_{2})^{2} -2x_{1}x_{2} = \frac{b^2-2ac}{a^2}$$

$${x_{1}}^{3}+{x_{2}}^{3}=(x_{1}+x_{2})\left ( (x_{1}+x_{2})^{2}-3x_{1}x_{2} \right )=\frac{3abc-b^3}{a^3}$$

$$\dots$$

**edit: 
   $$ {x_{1}}^{2}+{x_{2}}^{2}=\underset{\text{I also need this in all cases}}{{(x_{1}+x_{2})^{2} -2x_{1}x_{2}}} = \frac{b^2-2ac}{a^2} $$**

I need  $x_{1} ^ n + x_{2}^ n$ for any $n$ In terms of (Or as a function of)
$$ x_{1}+x_{2} $$  and  $$x_{1}x_{2}$$

Comment: `{x1, x2} = x /. Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]; f[n_] := Together@FullSimplify[x1^n + x2^n]; f[15]`

Comment: Thanks,I need the final structure in terms of x1 and x2 also for each case, not just the final result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`SymmetricReduction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SymmetricReduction.html) is a good tool for this:

```
First @ SymmetricReduction[x1^2+x2^2,{x1,x2}, {-b/a, c/a}]
First @ SymmetricReduction[x1^3+x2^3,{x1,x2}, {-b/a, c/a}]
First @ SymmetricReduction[x1^4+x2^4,{x1,x2}, {-b/a, c/a}]
```

> ```
> b^2/a^2-(2 c)/a
> -(b^3/a^3)+(3 b c)/a^2
> b^4/a^4-(4 b^2 c)/a^3+(2 c^2)/a^2
> ```

Comment: Thanks , I need the final structure in terms of x1 and x2 also for each case, not just the final result

Comment: `First @ SymmetricReduction[x1^4+x2^4, {x1, x2}]` ?

Comment: Watch what I edited

Comment: @zeros, and as Carl already said, `First @ SymmetricReduction[x1^3 + x2^3, {x1, x2}]` already displays the symmetric form explicitly; what is missing there?

Comment: ok, ok ,ok , Run in a new notebook and work thanks

Answer (score 6):

Recalling the relationship between sums of powers and linear recurrence relations, here is how one can use `LinearRecurrence[]` to generate the required expressions:

```
LinearRecurrence[{-b/a, -c/a}, {2, -b/a}, 5] // Simplify
   {2, -b/a, (b^2 - 2 a c)/a^2, -(b^3 - 3 a b c)/a^3, (b^4 - 4 a b^2 c + 2 a^2 c^2)/a^4}
```

Using `Inactivate[]` on the symmetric polynomials involved yields the expressions for the power sums in terms of symmetric polynomials of the roots:

```
LinearRecurrence[{Inactivate[x1 + x2], -Inactivate[x1 x2]},
                 {2, Inactivate[x1 + x2]}, 5] // Simplify // Activate

   {2, x1 + x2, -2 x1 x2 + (x1 + x2)^2, -3 x1 x2 (x1 + x2) + (x1 + x2)^3,
    2 x1^2 x2^2 - 4 x1 x2 (x1 + x2)^2 + (x1 + x2)^4}
```

---

Carl has already mentioned `SymmetricReduction[]` and its convenient third argument, if you're looking to explicitly display the [Newton-Girard formulae](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Newton-GirardFormulas.html). If you'll look at that last link, you'll see that a nice linear equation is satisfied between power sums and symmetric polynomials; you might want to try formulating this in terms of `LinearSolve[]`.

Comment: Watch what I edited

Answer (score 3):

One can obtan this as the solution to a certain recurrence equation. Call the nth term `f[n]`, and the roots `x1` and `x2`. Then

```
f[n] = (x1+x2)^n =
(x1+x2)*(x1^(n-1)+x2^(n-1)) - (x1*x2^(n-1)+x2*x1^(n-1)) =
(x1+x2)*(x1^(n-1)+x2^(n-1)) - x1*x2*(x1^(n-2)+x2^(n-2)) =
f[1]*f[n-1] - x1*x2*f[n-2]
```

Now suppose we make the quadratic monic, so it is `x^2-b*x+c` (the negative for the linear term coefficient is from expanding `(x-x1)*(x-x2)` and getting `x^2-(x+x2)*x+x1*x2`). With this convention, we have `f[1]==b` and we also require that `f[0]==2` (which is the sum of the roots to the zeroth power).

```
rtpowersums = 
 RSolveValue[{f[n] == b*f[n - 1] - c*f[n - 2], f[1] == b, f[0] == 2}, 
  f[n], n]

(* Out[213]= 2^-n ((b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c])^n + (b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 c])^n) *)
```

Quick test for case where roots are 2 and 3:

```
tt = Table[Expand[rtpowersums], {n, 1, 5}]
tt /. {b -> 5, c -> 6}

(* Out[214]= {b, b^2 - 2 c, b^3 - 3 b c, b^4 - 4 b^2 c + 2 c^2, 
 b^5 - 5 b^3 c + 5 b c^2}

Out[215]= {5, 13, 35, 97, 275} *)

Table[2^n + 3^n, {n, 5}]

(* Out[216]= {5, 13, 35, 97, 275} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's seem the `RootSum` is your after,of course,it just show the result.

```
RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, #^1 &] // FullSimplify
RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, #^2 &] // FullSimplify
RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, #^3 &] // FullSimplify
RootSum[a #^2 + b # + c &, #^4 &] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]